# Amazon route 53 with ha-proxy

Tags: amazon-route53

I'm using amazon route 53 for routing a DNS request to the load balancer. For load balancing i'm using ha-proxy load balancer route 53 route the request to the ha-proxy.

Here in route 53 I have given a weight 33.33% to the three load balancers. Suppose when client makes a request to route 53, route the request to the first ha-proxy server and tcp connection established.

So question is when client makes a second request where does it go? Is it possible that second request go to the first server where already tcp connection established?

[image]

There is three servers given in image and also there is route-53 client make request to the ha-proxy using route-53 DNS weighted.

Comment: Please describe what behavior you want, and explain why this behavior is desirable.  Where are the HAProxies located? Are they in EC2?  If so, are they in the same AWS region?   What services are you balancing? HTTP/HTTPS? Websockets? Something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot As Haproxy nodes are hosted on AWS EC2 instances and AWS Route 53 is routing TLS requests to these Haproxy nodes(hosted on EC2 instances) based on weightage given to each haproxy nodes on AWS Route 53 for balancing load to Haproxy nodes. As this basically for chat app, in which Haproxy nodes are transferring TLS requests to backend chat servers based on least_conn policy(not available in AWS ELB).In app, we don't know how many users will be there. So need to route requests to Haproxy nodes based on their memory usage and dynamically change weightage of each server in Route 53.

Answer (score 2):

Where the next request goes is not well-defined.  If you set a short TTL on the DNS responses, that assures less than you expect, because the client may disregard or not have access to the TTL information.

Yet, you still need short TTLs so that a client doesn't get stuck with the A record for a proxy that is out of service.

Weighting your DNS at 33.3% is probably not the best plan.  You can return the IP addresses of all healthy proxies with each DNS response -- there should be no need to balance the number of requests hitting each proxy.

Let me verify my understanding of the setup.  Assuming this is correct, the rest of the answer here should be applicable.

Scenario:

You have multiple HAProxy servers, mode tcp, terminating TLS, and balancing requests to back-end servers using leastconn so that the back-end server with the least number of connections will receive the next incoming connection.

Analysis:

You want things balanced on the back-end, so you don't need to weight the DNS responses on the front side to make this work correctly.  All you really need to do with DNS is health-check the proxies and don't advertise a proxy's IP address if it isn't healthy.  Otherwise, return all proxy addresses with with each DNS response.

Rationale:

It doesn't matter which proxy a client connects to.  Returning all addresses will return them in random order, and the client will arbitrarily use one.

Each proxy keeps its own count of the number of connections to each back-end and will always send connections to whichever back-end has the least connections *from its perspective*.  It doesn't need to know about the number of connections held by the other proxies, because *each proxy* is independently ensuring that the same number of connections is being sent to each back-end server.  Thus, at peak demand, the number of connections sent to each back-end by each proxy will be identical, +/- 1, within each proxy, and identical across proxies subject only to the randomness of DNS... and an imbalance on the front side cancels itself out, because if one IP address receives more traffic than the others, that only means the number of connections to *all* back-ends from that proxy is higher than the number from the others, but whatever that number is, it will still be +/- 1 at peak load -- and the distribution at peak load should be the only real concern you have.

As more clients disconnect than connect, you're leaving a period of peak demand (by definition), and the number of connections will tend to become less in-balance, but this doesn't matter either, because the proxy will level it right back out again as new connections arrive -- they'll automatically be given to the server with the fewest connections from that proxy's perspective, and we already postulated that at this point you aren't in peak demand, so the precise balance becomes less relevant.  The number of concurrent connections delivered to any one back-end server during off-peak will tend to never exceed the number of connections delivered to the server during peak with this configuration.